# Is で in 「...でおねがいします」 the "te form" of だ, or "circumstances" で particle?

Tags: grammar, particle-で, conversations

For orders & requests, I notice Japanese natives often add で after the thing they want. Here's a real-life example:

客:「この桜抹茶ラッテをひとつ、お願いします。」 (Customer: I'll have one of these sakura maccha lattes please.)

店員:「はい、わかりました。こちらホットとアイスがございますが。」 (Staff: Got it. We have this in hot or iced but (which do you want?))

客:「アイス**で**、お願いします。」 (Customer: Iced please.)

I know it's nitpicky, but what exactly is that で in アイスで?  Is it the "て form" of だ/です, or the "scope/condition/circumstances" で particle? Either of them seem like they could be appropriate. For clarity, here's examples of each to show that I mean:

山下先生は　日本人**で**　５０歳ぐらいです。 Yamashita-sensei is Japanese **and** about 50 years old. (The "て form" of だ/です to connect the phrases with "and")

山田さんは　18歳**で**　大学に　入りました。Yamada-san entered college at 18 years old. (で particle)

智也君は　一人**で**　人形を　作りました。Tomoya-kun made a figure by himself. (で particle)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a great question. I've thought of it sometimes but I concluded that both explanations can work, so I never bothered to clarify for myself. Thanks for asking this question for me!

Comment: Other than the examples provided, I've seem things like 「生ビールで」or「オレンジジュースで」when ordering at a restaurant. Seems like 「〜で（お願い）」is a common set phrase for ordering stuff

Comment: I think considering it as a particle is more reasonable, but you may know ウナギ文 (e.g. [this](https://www.nihongo-appliedlinguistics.net/wp/archives/9054)). In the similar manner, regarding じゃあ僕はウナギで, it could be argued that is a te-form of copula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a native speaker, I often try replacing a questionable で with でして or であり, and see if the sentence still makes sense:

- <sup>❌</sup>アイス**でして**お願いします。
- <sup>❌</sup>アイス**であり**お願いします。

These look incorrect to me, which means the original で is a particle.

The same で can also modify various other verbs:

- コーヒーをアイスで飲む。
- ピザをトッピングなしで注文する。
- 激辛で行ってみる？

In the following examples, something like お願いします is omitted, so I think these で are still particles:

- アイスで。
  Iced, please.
- 全部入りで。
  Everything.
- 以上で。
  That's it.

---

For comparison, here are examples where で is used as the te-form of だ. Either でして or であり also works:

- 私はアイス**で**ブラックのコーヒーが好きです。(joining two no-adjectives)
- 今日は暑いので、出されたコーヒーがアイス**で**良かった。(te-form for reason)
- 私はアイス**で**、彼はホットです。(["eel sentence"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/48986/5010))
- それが、昨日飲んだコーヒーがアイス**で**ね…。([で for 言いさし](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/60764/5010))

Comment: That "でして・であり test" is an interesting idea! Thanks for solidly answering the question.