# How to understand "で" and 献立 here?

Tags: grammar, words, copula

原文は、

> 目黒にある「バランス食品」では、糖尿病患者やダイエット中の人向けのメニューが用意されている。 **厳密なカロリー計算をした健康メニューで専門の栄養士が献立を考える**。

---

> 厳密なカロリー計算をした健康メニュー**で**専門の栄養士が献立を考える

これを

> 厳密なカロリー計算をした健康メニュー**を通じて**、専門の栄養士が献立を考える

として理解してもいいですか。

---

そして、**メニュー**と**献立**の違いはありますか。

私はGoogleで探しましたが、

[https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/献立](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E7%8C%AE%E7%AB%8B)

これによると、英語ではmenuの意味のようです。

この２つの意味は同じmenuなのに、menuでmenuを作るということですか。なんだか変だと思っています。

Comment: 関連大: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/24917/how-to-parse-%e4%b8%ad%e5%9b%bd%e4%ba%ba%e3%81%a7%e6%97%a5%e6%9c%ac%e8%aa%9e%e3%81%8c%e8%a9%b1%e3%81%9b%e3%82%8b%e6%96%b9%e3%81%af-%e3%81%8a%e9%9b%bb%e8%a9%b1%e3%81%8f%e3%81%a0%e3%81%95%e3%81%84

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「厳密なカロリー計算をした健康メニュー**で**専門の栄養士が献立を考える。」の「で」は、助詞ではなく、助動詞の「だ」の連用形です。

主語は書かれていませんが、前の文の「糖尿病患者やダイエット中の人向けのメニュー」のことを述べていて、「（それは）厳密なカロリー計算をした健康メニューだ。（そして、）専門の栄養士が献立を考える。」の二つの文をつないだものです。

メニューと献立は同じような意味ですが、この文脈では、「メニュー」は、レストランなどでお客さんが選べるように用意した料理の選択肢のことで、「献立」はそれぞれの料理の中の食材の組み合わせのことだと思います。