# Question about "nari"

Tags: conjugations, renyōkei

> 七三年にはテレビ番組になり、今も毎週続いています。

I understand the sentence to be:

> In '73 it became a television show, and today it continues every week.

My question is about the form of the verb なる in the above sentence – why is it "なり" here? When is the stem form of the verb used in this way?

Comment: Please ask one question per question.  I've edited out your question about 続いて, but please feel free to re-post it as a separate question.  If it helps, you can find the text of your original question here: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/revisions/8d98fb05-125e-437d-b02a-c163471a6d02/view-source

Answer (score 3):

> 「七三年{ななじゅうさんねん}にはテレビ番組{ばんぐみ}に**なり**、今{いま}も毎週続{まいしゅうつづ}いています。」

As you know, both verbs and adjectives conjugate in Japanese.  「なり」 is the 連用形{れんようけい} ("continuative form") of the verb 「なる」.

This sentence talks about two events -- 1) "It became a TV program." + 2) "It has continued to today."

「なる」 is the terminal form; therefore, it cannot be used mid-sentence to connect itself to another verb phrase.  Instead, you must use the continuative form 「なり」.

Read here and see how 「だ」 becomes 「で」 mid-sentence:

[How to parse 中国人で日本語が話せる方は、お電話ください。](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/24917/how-to-parse-%e4%b8%ad%e5%9b%bd%e4%ba%ba%e3%81%a7%e6%97%a5%e6%9c%ac%e8%aa%9e%e3%81%8c%e8%a9%b1%e3%81%9b%e3%82%8b%e6%96%b9%e3%81%af-%e3%81%8a%e9%9b%bb%e8%a9%b1%e3%81%8f%e3%81%a0%e3%81%95%e3%81%84)