# Is the で in ～が原因で～ the copula?

Tags: grammar, copula

In constructs like ～が原因で起こった～ is the で the て form of だ?

For example in:
旦那や子どもへの嫉妬が原因で起こったママ友トラブル

I assume it is for the が to make sense, but I can't find any information on this, so if anyone knows an answer would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you post the whole sentences?  Right now, the answer is clear only with the first phrase.

Comment: @l'électeur I just added an example sentence, and I removed ～が理由で～ since I only added that as an afterthought to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 「旦那{だんな}や子{こ}どもへの嫉妬{しっと}が原因{げんいん}**で**起{お}こったママ友{とも}トラブル」

That 「で」 is a particle and not a copula.

It can generally be said that 「で」 would be a particle unless it could grammatically and contextually be replaced by 「であり」、「であって」、「であり、そして」, etc.

In the phrase in question, the 「で」 cannot be replaced by one of those phrases.

A good example of the copula 「で」 can be seen in this Q&A:

[How to parse 中国人で日本語が話せる方は、お電話ください。](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/24917/how-to-parse-%e4%b8%ad%e5%9b%bd%e4%ba%ba%e3%81%a7%e6%97%a5%e6%9c%ac%e8%aa%9e%e3%81%8c%e8%a9%b1%e3%81%9b%e3%82%8b%e6%96%b9%e3%81%af-%e3%81%8a%e9%9b%bb%e8%a9%b1%e3%81%8f%e3%81%a0%e3%81%95%e3%81%84)

If you had a sentence such as:

> 「トラブルの原因はＡ**で**、Ｂではない。」

then, that 「で」 in bold would certainly be a copula in the 連用形{れんようけい} ("continuative form").

Comment: As a side note, the particle で as in the example sentence is the same で as in the copula -- the copular uses of で are a more recent development, deriving from the use of particle で in the phrasal copular construction ～であり.  In modern Japanese, the particle で is functionally and semantically different from the copular で, even though historically they come from the same thing.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I had always previously thought of it as the particle, but for some reason this time I started focusing on the が more and that in turn made me start questioning whether the で was actually the copula or not.